# ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'] is nil while trying to get nginx to play with rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nginx, rvm

I want to nginx to serve a rails app. I've set up my gems using an rvm gemset. From the [directions](https://rvm.io/integration/passenger/) to get nginx to load my gemset, I made a config/setup_load_paths.rb file:

```
if ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'] && ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'].include?('rvm')
  begin
    rvm_path     = File.dirname(File.dirname(ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME']))
    rvm_lib_path = File.join(rvm_path, 'lib')
    puts rvm_lib_path.inspect
    $LOAD_PATH.unshift rvm_lib_path
    require 'rvm'
    RVM.use_from_path! File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__))
  rescue LoadError
    # RVM is unavailable at this point.
    raise "RVM ruby lib is currently unavailable."
  end
end

ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = File.expand_path('../Gemfile', File.dirname(__FILE__))
require 'bundler/setup'
```

This doesn't seem to do it. So trying to debug, I found that `ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME']` is actually Nil and hence the first block of code doesn't even run. Why is this Nil, and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: What if you placed the file in `config/initializers/setup_load_path.rb` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are following old instructions, visit https://rvm.io/integration/passenger/ again and use the proper code in `config/setup_load_paths.rb`:

```
if ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'] && ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'].include?('rvm')
  begin
    gems_path = ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'].split(/@/)[0].sub(/rubies/,'gems')
    ENV['GEM_PATH'] = "#{gems_path}:#{gems_path}@global"
    require 'rvm'
    RVM.use_from_path! File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__))
  rescue LoadError
    raise "RVM gem is currently unavailable."
  end
end

# If you're not using Bundler at all, remove lines bellow
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = File.expand_path('../Gemfile', File.dirname(__FILE__))
require 'bundler/setup'
```